# Decoding h264 frames from RTP stream

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, rtp

I am using live555 and ffmpeg libraries to get and decode RTP H264 stream from server; Video stream was encoded by ffmpeg, using Baseline profile and

```
x264_param_default_preset(m_params, "veryfast", "zerolatency")
```

I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330764/ffmpeg-cant-decode-h264-stream-frame-data/) and add SPS and PPS data in the every frame, which I receive from network;

```
void ClientSink::NewFrameHandler(unsigned frameSize, unsigned numTruncatedBytes,
    timeval presentationTime, unsigned durationInMicroseconds)
{
     ...
EncodedFrame tmp;
    tmp.m_frame = std::vector<unsigned char>(m_tempBuffer.data(), m_tempBuffer.data() + frameSize);
    tmp.m_duration = durationInMicroseconds;
    tmp.m_pts = presentationTime;

    //Add SPS and PPS data into the frame; TODO: some devices may send SPS and PPs data already into frame;
    tmp.m_frame.insert(tmp.m_frame.begin(), m_spsPpsData.cbegin(), m_spsPpsData.cend());

    emit newEncodedFrame( SharedEncodedFrame(tmp) );
    m_frameCounter++;

    this->continuePlaying();
}
```

And this frames I receive in the decoder.

```
bool H264Decoder::decodeFrame(SharedEncodedFrame orig_frame)
{
...
while(m_packet.size > 0)
    {
        int got_picture;
        int len = avcodec_decode_video2(m_decoderContext, m_picture, &got_picture, &m_packet);
        if (len < 0)
        {
            emit criticalError(QString("Decoding error"));
            return false;
        }
        if (got_picture)
        {
            std::vector<unsigned char> result;
            this->storePicture(result);

            if ( m_picture->format == AVPixelFormat::AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P )
            {
                //QImage img = QImage(result.data(), m_picture->width, m_picture->height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
                Frame_t result_rgb;
                if (!convert_yuv420p_to_rgb32(result, m_picture->width, m_picture->height, result_rgb))
                {
                    emit criticalError( QString("Failed to convert YUV420p image into rgb32; can't create QImage!"));
                    return false;
                }
                unsigned char* copy_img = new unsigned char[result_rgb.size()];
//this needed because QImage shared buffer, which used, and it will crash, if i use this qimage after result_rgb deleting
                std::copy(result_rgb.cbegin(), result_rgb.cend(), copy_img);
                QImage img = QImage(copy_img, m_picture->width, m_picture->height, QImage::Format_RGB32,
                [](void* array)
                {
                    delete[] array;
                }, copy_img);
                img.save(QString("123.bmp"));
                emit newDecodedFrame(img);
            }
```

avcodec_decode_video2 decode frames without any error message, but decoded frames, after converting it (from yuv420p into rgb32) is invalid. Example of image available on [this link](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6712/157039962.6/0_a9d98_2a5fa1a6_orig)

Do you have any ideas what I make wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the error is in the convert_yuv420p_to_rgb32() code. Try this:

```
static SwsContext *m_swsCtx = NULL;
QImage frame =  QImage ( m_picture->width, m_picture->height,
                         QImage::Format_RGB32 );
m_swsCtx = sws_getCachedContext ( m_swsCtx, m_picture->width,
                                  m_picture->height, PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                  m_picture->width, m_picture->height,
                                  AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32, SWS_BICUBIC,
                                  NULL, NULL, NULL );
uint8_t *dstSlice[] = { frame.bits() };
int dstStride = frame.width() * 4;
sws_scale ( m_swsCtx, &m_picture.data, &m_picture.linesize,
            0, m_picture->height, dstSlice, &dstStride );
```

You will need to include/link swscale if you have not does so already.

Note: you don't need SPS/PPS every frame (on keyframes is good enough). But it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Your code work better then my previous version. But now frame looks like this http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/9351/157039962.6/0_a9d9a_5a5fdaee_orig    May be it is my error(decoder received not all encoded frames, sended to it by RTSPClient)

Comment: Not sure, but i'm guessing it has to do with how you are inserting SPS/PPS. Is the encoder producing more that one slice per frame? If so, inserting the SPS/PPS int the middle of an AU, the decoder will think the frame ended before it has.

Comment: I don't know how much slices per frame encoder produce(how I can check it?). But all input frames are not fragmented - I use "int fragment_type = Data[0] & 0x1F;" and fragment_type is not equal 28. If I add SPS and PPS data to the begin of frame - decoder decode only half of frame :( If I don't add SPS and PPS decoder don't decode any frame;

Comment: Ok. I fix problem. I add this line at the decoder initialization method: m_decoderContext->flags2 |= CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS;

Answer (score 4):

Ok. This my simple example, which decode H264 stream, which received from liveMedia library. It can decode frames, which are truncated not only at boundary of frames.

```
   class H264Decoder : public AbstractDecoder
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        H264Decoder( QObject* parent = nullptr );
        virtual ~H264Decoder();

    public slots:

        virtual bool decodeFrame(SharedEncodedFrame orig_frame) override;

    signals:
        //sended when we have new decoded frame
        void newDecodedFrame( QImage img );

    protected:
        void storePicture(std::vector<unsigned char>& res);

        AVCodec* m_decoder;
        AVCodecContext* m_decoderContext;
        int m_got_picture;
        AVFrame* m_picture;
        AVPacket m_packet;
    };
```

And this is realization:

```
#include "H264Decoder.hpp"
#include "ImgConverting.hpp"
#include <QPixmap>
extern "C"
{
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

using namespace std;

H264Decoder::H264Decoder( QObject *parent)
    : AbstractDecoder(parent), m_decoder(nullptr), m_decoderContext(nullptr),
      m_got_picture(0), m_picture(nullptr)
{
    avcodec_register_all();
    av_init_packet(&m_packet);
    m_decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!m_decoder)
    {
        QString str = QString("Can't find H264 decoder!");
        emit criticalError(str);
    }
    m_decoderContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_decoder);

    if (m_decoder->capabilities & CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED)
        m_decoderContext->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;


    //we can receive truncated frames
    m_decoderContext->flags2 |= CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS;
    m_decoderContext->thread_count = 4;//TODO: random value. May be changing can make decoding faster

    AVDictionary* dictionary = nullptr;
    if (avcodec_open2(m_decoderContext, m_decoder, &dictionary) < 0)
    {
        QString str = QString("Failed to open decoder!");
        emit criticalError(str);
    }
    qDebug() << "H264 Decoder successfully opened";
    m_picture = avcodec_alloc_frame();
}

H264Decoder::~H264Decoder()
{
    qDebug() << "ACHTUNG!!! H264Decoder deleted!!!\r\n\r\n";
    if (m_decoderContext)
    {
        avcodec_close(m_decoderContext);
        delete m_decoderContext;
    }
}


bool H264Decoder::decodeFrame(SharedEncodedFrame orig_frame)
{
    Frame_t enc_frame;
    orig_frame >> enc_frame;
    m_packet.size = enc_frame.size();
    m_packet.data = enc_frame.data();

    qDebug() << "H264Decoder: received encoded frame with framesize " << enc_frame.size();

    while(m_packet.size > 0)
    {
        int got_picture;
        int len = avcodec_decode_video2(m_decoderContext, m_picture, &got_picture, &m_packet);
        if (len < 0)
        {
            QString err("Decoding error");
            qDebug() << err;
            return false;
        }
        if (got_picture)
        {
            qDebug() << "H264Decoder: frame decoded!";
            std::vector<unsigned char> result;
            this->storePicture(result);

            if ( m_picture->format == PIX_FMT_YUV420P )
            {
                static SwsContext *m_swsCtx = NULL;
                QImage frame_img = QImage(m_picture->width, m_picture->height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
                m_swsCtx = sws_getCachedContext ( m_swsCtx, m_picture->width,
                    m_picture->height, PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                    m_picture->width, m_picture->height,
                    PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_GAUSS,
                    NULL, NULL, NULL );
                uint8_t *dstSlice[] = { frame_img.bits() };
                int dstStride = frame_img.width() * 3;
                if (sws_scale ( m_swsCtx, m_picture->data, m_picture->linesize,
                    0, m_picture->height, dstSlice, &dstStride ) != m_picture->height )
                {
                    qDebug() << "PIZDETS!!!";
                    exit(-5);
                }
                qDebug() << "New decoded image!";
                emit newDecodedFrame(frame_img);
            }
            else if (m_picture->format == PIX_FMT_RGB32)
            {
                QImage img = QImage(result.data(), m_picture->width, m_picture->height, QImage::Format_RGB32);
                qDebug() << "New decoded image!";
                emit newDecodedFrame(img);
            }
            else if (m_picture->format == PIX_FMT_RGB24)
            {
                QImage img = QImage(result.data(), m_picture->width, m_picture->height, QImage::Format_RGB888);
                qDebug() << "New decoded image!";
                emit newDecodedFrame(img);
            }
            else
            {
                QString err = QString( "Unsupported pixel format! Can't create QImage!");
                qDebug() << err;
                emit criticalError( err );
                return false;
            }
        }
        m_packet.size -= len;
        m_packet.data += len;
    }

    return true;
}

void H264Decoder::storePicture(std::vector<unsigned char>& res)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS; i++)
    {
        std::copy(m_picture->data[i], m_picture->data[i] + 
            m_picture->linesize[i]*m_picture->height, std::back_inserter(res));
    }
}
```

I send newDecodedFrame to GUI thread, where this QImage will be drawn at some widget.

P.S: This comment is very long for posting as comment's comment