# Why my App cannot decode the RTSP stream?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, rtsp, rtp, live555

I use live555 to receive RTP video frame  (frame encoded in H264).  I use Live555 open my local .sdp file to receive frame data.   I just saw DummySink::afterGettingFrame  was called  ceaselessly。  if fReceiveBuffer in DummySink is correct,  Why FFMPEG cannot decode the frame?   My code is wrong?

Here is my Code Snippet:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12529740/

the function  avcodec_decode_video2 is always return failed , its value less than zero

fReceiveBuffer is present one video frame？

Oh, Here is my FFMPEG init code need to open related video decoder:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12529760/

Comment: Please ask make your question easier to understand. Describe what you already tried. Make approach comprehensible for us.

Comment: @SebastianAnnies Finally, I find the solution for the question.  Thank you remind me of this

Answer (score 0):

I read the document related H264 again， I found out that I-frame(IDR) need SPS/PPS separated by 0x00000001 insert into the header and decoder have a capacity to decode the frame  correctly.  Here is a related solution 
[FFmpeg can't decode H264 stream/frame data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330764/ffmpeg-cant-decode-h264-stream-frame-data/)

[Decoding h264 frames from RTP stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857737/decoding-h264-frames-from-rtp-stream)

and now, My App  works fine,  it can decode the frame and convert it to OSD Image for displaying to screen .