# h264 decoding rtsp link error

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, h.264, rtsp

I am receiving RTSP stream with live555 library and decode them with ffmpeg. 
At first, i couldnt decode data's that come from live555. After a little search i learned that I needed to include the sequence (SPS) and picture parameter sets (PPS) for my frame data before sending frame to the FFmpeg.

header : 00 00 00 01 67 4d 00 14 95 b8 58 25 90 00 00 00 01 68 ee 3c 80 00 00 00 01

[FFmpeg can't decode H264 stream/frame data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330764/ffmpeg-cant-decode-h264-stream-frame-data/)

Now i can take frame but a tiny problem comes out. [![enter image description here][1]][1]

3 packets still have problem. FFmpeg cant decode them i am suggesting they are special command. Because they are so small 9,4 and 5 byte come.

Here they are

[h264 @ 0x137c00] no frame!
00 00 00 01 67 4d 00 14 95 b8 58 25 90 00 00 00 01 68 ee 3c 80 00 00 00 01 67 4d 00 14 95 b8 58 25 90 
[h264 @ 0x137c00] no frame!
00 00 00 01 67 4d 00 14 95 b8 58 25 90 00 00 00 01 68 ee 3c 80 00 00 00 01 68 ee 3c 80 
[h264 @ 0x137c00] no frame!
00 00 00 01 67 4d 00 14 95 b8 58 25 90 00 00 00 01 68 ee 3c 80 00 00 00 01 06 e5 01 ec 80 
[h264 @ 0x137c00] no frame!

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packet starting with 00 00 00 01 67 is your SPS, and 00 00 00 01 68 is your PPS. You probably want to use the h264 [AVParser](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__parsing.html) which will combine PPS/SPS/frame into single packets, which is what the ffh264 decoder expects. A typical RTSP stream (or any network stream) will repeat the PPS/SPS every few seconds or so.

Comment: i am confused. I am going to combine these 3 packet into a single one. The format of packet should not change should it ? Also what happen if i should ignore there packets ?

Comment: FFmpeg expects one AVPacket going into a video decoder to be one frame. What's inside the AVPacket, in the case of h264, is all NALs needed to make up one single frame, including all non-frame NALs preceeding it. So yes, you concatenate SPS, PPS and all frame NALs inside a single AVPacket. You can probably discard the SPS/PPS if you really want to, just make sure they were included before the first frame sent to the decoder.

Comment: i realized after these 3 packets a huge packet(5500 byte) comes which start with 00 00 00 01 65 . İ learned these packet IDR picture. I will going to try all of these a single packet. İf i cant i am going to ignore all of these nals. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i might have solved problem. I added Parsing operation before decoding frames.

```
avparser= av_parser_init(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
len= av_parser_parse2(avparser,mCodecContext,&data,&lenght_parse,encodedFrame,encodedFrameSize,0,0,0);
while(encodedFrameSize)
{
    len= av_parser_parse2(avparser,mCodecContext,&data,&lenght_parse,encodedFrame,encodedFrameSize,0,0,0);
    encodedFrame     += len;
    encodedFrameSize  -=len;
        if(lenght_parse)
        {
            av_init_packet(&pkt);
            pkt.data=data;
            pkt.size=lenght_parse;
            length = avcodec_decode_video2(mCodecContext,decodedFrame,&gotFrame,&pkt);
        }
}
```

I tested app yesterday and a new problem came out. Application stops streaming after 4-5 hours. I think problem is based on decoding operation. Now i am trying to solve that.

Day by day, I'm approaching to solution !!