# How to decide raw h264 using pyav?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, live555

I am playing `pylive555` (Please [refer to this article.](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2013/11/pulling-h264-video-from-ip-camera-using.html)) against my web cams. I am able to get the bytes of each frame (be it i frame, p frame, or b frame) out using the code listed in the article.

However, what comes next will be to decode the bytes into an actual frame image or numpy array (just i frame, p frame, or b frame themselves, not applying delta onto the i frames when it comes to p frame or b frame).

I did some research online and found that a we might be able to use `avcodec_decode_video2` function [like it's said in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330764/ffmpeg-cant-decode-h264-stream-frame-data). Has anybody done this with pyAv? Do you mind sharing how you did it?